# How to add space between border and object inside the border

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have Widget created using HTML & CSS which looks fine but i unable to add some space between the inside Objects & Border line. Can anyone please help me on this.

```css
.solid { border-style: solid; }
```

```html
<div class="solid">
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" ng-model="c.data.message" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
   <button type="submit" ng-click="c.add()" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is my output currently

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjXBE.png)

Comment: add padding? ...

Comment: What do you mean by "between the inside Objects & Border line"? What elements are you referring to? Also, in your example you open three divs but only close one.

Comment: You simply cant mark Negative marks it was a typo sir. Just a note if my code was not correct i definitely should not get the output too without closing <divs>

Comment: @AbdulAzeez who are you addressing that comment to? I've not downvoted your question at all. However, it is perfectly reasonable to downvote a question if it is unclear or the question itself contains errors and misdirections that may affect the responses. For example, I could have posted an answer stating that your invalid html was preventing your padding from being applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use padding like this

```
.input-group{ padding: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a css class to your div which need to be padded

```css
.solid { border-style: solid; }

.padded {
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="solid">
  <div class="input-group padded">
    <input type="text" ng-model="c.data.message" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" ng-click="c.add()" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```